# Can't use update prepared statement twice

Tags: php

For some reason I can't use this statement... I always get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in. I editing two  columns so I have it twice.

My code:

```
        $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Notes".$_SESSION["id"]." SET title=? WHERE id=".$id);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $stmttitle);

        // set parameters and execute
        $stmttitle = $title;
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Notes".$_SESSION["id"]." SET note=? WHERE id=".$id);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $stmtnote);

        // set parameters and execute
        $stmtnote = $note;
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Declare `$stmtnote` before `bind_param()` function

Comment: @Marvin yes  its mysqli

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik It didnt help

Comment: Please output `$conn->error` directly after `$conn->prepare` and tell me what it says.

Comment: It says "Unknown column '1$date' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Then what is `$id`?

Comment: @Marvin Thanks for help.... I had errors with redirecting... prepared statements are without errors

Comment: What not bind the id as a parameter as well?